# How to disable cascade delete for many-to-many relationships between some tables in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, many-to-many

My question is a bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726014/selectively-disabling-cascade-delete-on-many-to-many-link-table), although I use EF6.
The problem is that I have two entities which are connected through a mapping table - and have a many-to-many relationship like this for example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
            .HasMany(t => t.Members)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("TeamMemberMapping");
            });
```

So in this example one team can have multiple members and one guy can be a part of multiple teams.

The problem with this is when I delete a guy, all his team mappings will be deleted, because Entity Framework uses cascade delete by default as a delete action.

I'd like to turn this off - so the DB shouldn't allow to delete a guy, if he is a part of some team.

I know that I can remove the many-to-many cascade delete convention globally with this:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

But this is too harsh for me. I would like to do this only for this table.

My other idea is (since I use code-first migrations) removing the convention just temporarily, so I can generate an update step which would drop all the foreign keys:

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.TeamMemberMapping", "Employee_Id", "dbo.Employee");
DropForeignKey("dbo.TeamMemberMapping", "Team_Id", "dbo.Team");
DropForeignKey("dbo.SomeOtherMapping", "Some_Id", "dbo.SomeTable");
DropForeignKey("dbo.SomeOtherMapping", "Other_Id", "dbo.OtherTable");

AddForeignKey("dbo.TeamMemberMapping", "Employee_Id", "dbo.Employee", "Id");
AddForeignKey("dbo.TeamMemberMapping", "Team_Id", "dbo.Team", "Id");
AddForeignKey("dbo.SomeOtherMapping", "Some_Id", "dbo.SomeTable", "Id");
AddForeignKey("dbo.SomeOtherMapping", "Other_Id", "dbo.OtherTable", "Id");
```

Now I can edit this migration to skip all the other mappings (like "SomeOtherMapping") and only deal with "TeamMemberMapping".

Then I would revert my temporary change (e.g. removing the convention)

Is there any drawbacks of this solution? Because it seems to be a workaround for me.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Your db design has cascade delete, but your business rules do not need it. The architecture of your system should be governed by the business requirements, not other way around. Remove it from the db if it's not required. DB design should support your business rules 100%, not 99%.

Comment: _"Remove it from the db if it's not required."_

It is required on one place but not on the other.
I would like to not create this as a DB update step, but instead express it with the modelbuilder API. 
Although it seems that it's not possible, there is no such thing like `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: In my opinion, cascade delete is an extreme end of a foreign key relationship. You should use it only if you need it 100% of the times. But in your case, it's not like that. If I were you, I would have removed cascade delete and handle that in my data layer code.

Comment: Yes, that could be also a solution. However, I don't see cascade delete as an extreme in any sense. For some relationships you need it, for some, you don't. It should be configurable.

Comment: It is not configurable. Forget about EF; Think  from the database point of view. When you remove cascade delete from a relationship, even for 2 minutes, it becomes effective for every single database session. Some of these sessions may need cascade delete, some may not. How do you differentiate? That's why I said it is extreme and it effects every single user. I hope you are familiar with DDL and DML. Otherwise this will not make any sense.

Comment: For some relationships, I need cascade delete (for all sessions). For some relationships, I don't. It's that simple.