# Entity Framework Many To Many with TPT Approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, table-per-type

What I try to reach is an NM relationship between AbstractUser and Plant in use with TPT inheritance.

[image]

When I try to configure the relationship,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Plant>().HasMany(c => c.RemindedByUsers).WithMany().Map(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("UserHasRemindedPlant");
});
```

I get the following exeption:

> Additional information: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.UserHasRemindedPlant_dbo.AbstractUsers_AbstractUser_Id' on
>   table 'UserHasRemindedPlant' may cause cycles or multiple cascade
>   paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify
>   other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

How do I set the ON DELETE or ON UPDATE action on many to many releationships on tpt abstract entities?

When I use the line above everything works fine but I need this convention for other entities.

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Here my entity classes:

**AbstractUser**

```
public abstract class AbstractUser
{
    protected AbstractUser()
    {
        RemindedPlants = new Collection<Plant>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...


    [Required]
    public SchoolYear SchoolYear { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Plant> RemindedPlants { get; private set; }
}
```

**Studend**

```
[Table("Student")]
public class Student : AbstractUser
{
    //some unrelevant props here

}
```

**Teacher**

```
[Table("Teacher")]

public class Teacher : AbstractUser
{
    //some unrelevant props here

}
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. If it works when removing the `OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention` the problem can't be the many-to-many relationship. Does for example the `Plant` have a (required) reference to a user (AbstractUser or one of the derived users)? This would indeed cause multiple delete paths from the `AbstractUser` table to the `UserHasRemindedPlant` table and throw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You must disable cascading delete with Fluent API `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Plant>().HasMany(c => c.RemindedByUsers).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false).Map(m =>{
m.ToTable("UserHasRemindedPlant");});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For some reason, visual studio cannot resolve WillCascadeOnDelete(false) after WithMany(). Has this changed after EF6?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: EF: 6.0.2
Dot.Net: 4.5

Comment: Then you should have no problems in using WillCascadeOnDelete(false). what do you get on AutoComplete after WithMany()?

Comment: GetType, Map, MapToStoredProcedures. If I choose WithOptional or WithRequired "WillCascadeOnDelete" is available, but not after WithMany :/

Comment: I did not notice WithRequired is needed to call WillCascadeOnDelete.

Comment: So there is no possible way to solve this? Maybe overwriting OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention and skip these two entities? Or disable the convention globaly and enable it if needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705637/491181