# Display an error page in ASP.NET MVC when a user attempts to delete an object with Foreign Key constraints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm really new to ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework and it's giving me so many headaches. I've gone through all of the similar questions and I've come up empty. I cannot find any good resources on ASP.NET MVC Error Handling!

Here are my models:

```
namespace ServerManager.Models
{
    public class Domain
    {
        public Domain()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.Servers = new HashSet<Server>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Domain Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Fully-Qualified Name")]
        public string FullyQualifiedName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Servers")]
        public virtual ICollection<Server> Servers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Server
    {
        public Server()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(25)]
        [Display(Name="Server Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Domain Domain { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Domain")]
        public virtual Guid DomainId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm looking to be able to access the `Server.Domain` property to lazily access the `Domain` for the `Server` object I'm working with (which works) and conversely, I'm looking to access the `Domain.Servers` property (which kind of works). The problem is that when I delete a `Domain` object using the `DbContext`, a cascading delete takes place. The desired effect that I'm going for is to not allow the user to delete a `Domain` object while there are still `Server` objects using the `Domain`. How can I achieve this without displaying a generic Error message?

Comment: In your context class you can override the method OnModelCreating and set the cascade options. Some articles [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/12/17/ef4-cpt5-code-first-remove-cascading-deletes.aspx), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165720/Using-the-Code-First-Model-Configuration-Classes) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705441/how-to-disable-cascade-delete-for-link-tables-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: Yeah, buddy. As indicated in the question, I've looked at all of those links before and Fluent caused more problems for me in the end. It's probably that I don't fully understand how to map relationships using Fluent as of yet, so maybe I can look into it a bit more.

Comment: Dont see those or fluent referenced in your question. This is the way to go if you really want the correct cascade rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you write a query like this to find the Domain object:

```
Guid id = Guid.Parse("...");
Domain domain = db.Domains.Find(id);
```

You can write another query to determine if it has any Servers:

```
bool hasServers = db.Servers.Any(s => s.DomainId == domain.Id);
```

You could also combine it into a single query:

```
var domainAndServers = db.Domains.Include("Servers").SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == id);
```

Or something like this:

```
var domainAndServerCount = from d in db.Domains
                           where d.Id == id
                           select new
                           {
                               Domain = d,
                               ServerCount = d.Servers.Count()
                           };
```

You can use those properties to populate your view model whether you can allow deletion or not:

```
DomainViewModel vm = new DomainViewModel();
vm.CanBeDeleted = hasServers;
// or
vm.CanBeDeleted = domain.Servers.Count() > 0;
```

The domain.Servers.Count() > 0 will work if you have lazy loading, so you wouldn't necessarily need to write your query using Include.

Comment: To be honest, you're totally right! I was over-complicating it in my head. Just as a side note, I also updated the POST action for Delete so that it throws a `NotSupportedException` if the `domain.Servers.Count()` is greater than 0. That way you can't submit a POST request to delete the Domain, which will cause a cascade delete to occur.