# Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, migration, entity

Everything went well until 2 days ago, I had inserted things in database before, but suddenly it gave me an error (don't remember it as it got fixed) but error after error I'm still stuck and can't insert a record in my DB.

The error I get now is: Invalid object name 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'.
I searched Google and found 3 relevant issues but the procedures didn't solved my issue...

I tried in nuget with the command to enable migration also.

I truly don't understand how this is appearing all of a sudden.
I didn't change anything except codelogic.

I updated to the new version of entity & VS update 2 couple days ago, idk maybe that is the cause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run following commands in package console managers:-

```
add-migration MigrationName
```

This will add new migration class to your project. Now run:-

```
update-database -verbose
```

This will fix your issue and will re-create "dbo.__MigrationHistory" table.

Comment: When trying the first command i get : "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Hotel_System'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration)."

Comment: And i tryed the Enable-Migrations but it gave me this error : "No context type was found in the assembly 'Hotel_System'."

Comment: You please make sure your should have class implemented by DbContext in "Hotel_System" assembly.
Also see the name of connection string passed to it?

Comment: This is my Dbcontext class :  http://imgur.com/xknJ1BC  and this is my connectionstring name : http://imgur.com/tEUZikT ,i never modified it , it was running fine in the past.Now strange thing is , im debugging it again and now im facing a new error :  "Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=2593; handshake=0; "

Comment: If this is the case then you need to check your connection string if it correct to establish connection with database and also check SQL server service is up.

Comment: My connection string is this : http://imgur.com/rjqUDOR , my solution : http://imgur.com/RuoGlY2 , Constructor of first window : http://imgur.com/trNipEZ , Method where its throwing exception : http://imgur.com/dF8epQv , SQL server is running : http://imgur.com/DEiolk3 .

Comment: ok so i uninstalled 2016 version off slq sever management studio , and guess what , error is gone.I still have some other issue " FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Rooms_dbo.Floors_Floor_FloorID' on table 'Rooms' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.", i have specified in class Room that floor is required , specified in class Floor that its the table floors it should use. im lost ...

Comment: That's great your error is gone. Now your error shows, your are trying to insert floor Id in rooms which is not present in floors table. If foreign key constraint is not required then remove it from model or by migration class.

Comment: Im trying to insert an Account not a floor or room.How can you remove it form migration since i removed it from model but with no result?I really appreciate your help Sandeep ! My floor model :  http://imgur.com/uWJMo0t  my room model : http://imgur.com/WskdPIh . i also tryed making the ID from room nullable but didn't work.

Comment: you can remove constraint in OnModelCreating via modelBuilder and by updated model class.
But here you should try add-migration once again to see if your database schema is in sync with your model classes.

If you found some discrepancies, then you need to update-database.
Please let me know, if it helps you.

Comment: "remove constraint in OnModelCreating via modelBuilder"  to be honest i don't know how to do that. this is what you mean but i don't know where to set this. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705441/how-to-disable-cascade-delete-for-link-tables-in-ef-code-first).The add-Migration didn't work.(same error as before).Im still learning Entity framework as you can see :) .Thank you for your help so far !

Answer (score 1):

So this is solved ... I saw that i had a Property 'Building' in my Class 'Room' , that was creating the foreign key constraint error since 'Room' has a Floor , and Floor has a Building , the building property in Room was creating that issue . It was there from the beginning i started the project , and yeah didn't removed it  :)  THANK YOU VERRY MUCH FOR YOU'RE HELP Sandeep ! Have a good day / night !

Comment: Good to hear your issue has been resolved. :) Have nice day/night to you too.