# Prevent Entity Framework from setting foreign key to NULL

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Our database has three entities: `Person`, `Company` and `PhoneCall`.

`Person` describes an individual. `Company` describes a company. `PhoneCall` describes the details of a phone call to either a `Person` or `Company`.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string VatNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneCall
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public int Duration { get; set;}

    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

I am seeing certain undesirable behavior with Entity Framework when deleting a `Person` or `Company`.

If I delete a `Person`, entity framework is updating any associated `PhoneCall` entries and setting `PersonId` to NULL.

```
dbContext.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Deleted;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Instead of Entity Framework setting `PersonId` to null on all of the associated `PhoneCall` entries, what I would like is for entity framework throw some kind exception to let me know that the `Person` cannot be deleted because there are related entities referencing said `Person`.

The problem seems to be that entity framework doesn't respect the `PhoneCall.PersonId` and `PhoneCall.CompanyId` foreign keys since they are both (necessarily) nullable.

I can obviously perform my own check before deletion like so:

```
if (phoneCallDbSet.Where(ph => ph.Person == personToDelete).Any())
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot delete person with associated calls");
```

...but my preference would be to set up a some kind of restriction that prevents Entity Framework from setting the foreign key to NULL in the first place, so that if a developer forgets to perform this check, we don't end up with entries in the `PhoneCall` table linking to nothing.

Is this possible?

Comment: changing the type of foreignkey-column instead `int?` to `int` makes the relationship to not-nullable. or why are they neccessarily nullable? Either they may be nullable, so the relation can be null or they may not be nullable and a relation is needed. every thing else you do with cascase delete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable cascade delete for link tables in EF code-first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705441/how-to-disable-cascade-delete-for-link-tables-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: The two columns are nullable because a Phone call can be made to either a Company OR a Person.

Comment: If I delete a Person in the database with an SQL query it does enforce the foreign key constraint and prevents the person from being deleted... it's just Entity framework giving me trouble because of this automatic NULL setting behavior.

Comment: Your schema assumes, that your PhoneCall entity can exist without both Person and Company set, so you might need to rearrange your schema to not allow for that - either with some inheritance or many-to-many for your PhoneCall-Company, PhoneCall-Person relationship. Another way is also to extract a base class for Company/Person, but that might limit your options in future for inheritance for those two.

Comment: Do you have a join table for each relationship?  (i. e. CompanyPhoneCall and PersonPhoneCall tables?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No!! There is no way to achieve what you want without having explicit checks in your code.

If we set the property as nullable, we tell the framework that you can set it to null if required. Then why would it show any error when it is set to null?

Either you make the property non-nullable or have explicit checks in your code to handle it.

Comment: I figured as much, thank you for your response. As an alternative, what do you think about manually creating a trigger in the database that prevents updates to the columns? We'll still do the explicit checks, but this would prevent the columns being set to null in the event that somebody forgot to do an explicit check.

Comment: yeah!! That's what I have seen many people do in such cases. Triggers sound like a good idea. You would have consistent data which you want.