# Set to default instead delete cascade

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am making code first entity framework database model, and I am struggeling with cascade delete. There are my simple classes:

```
public class User {
    [Key()]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public int CampaignId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("CampaignId")]
    public virtual Campaign Campaign {get; set;}
}

public class Campaign {
    [Key()]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}

    public virtual List<User> Users {get; set;}

    public Campaign() {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to assign one campaign to every user. When I delete campaign which is assigned by user:

```
internal static void DeleteCampaign(Campaign campaignToDelete) {
            using (var context = new DatabaseContext()) {
                context.Entry(campaignToDelete).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Users assigned to that campaign are deleted too. What I want is to not delete users, but assign them to first avaible campaign, or null. For some reason I cant do something like that:

```
internal static void DeleteCampaign(Campaign campaignToDelete) {
            using (var context = new DatabaseContext()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < campaignToDelete.Users.Count; i++) {
                    campaignToDelete.Users[i].Campaign = context.Campaigns.ElementAt(0);
                }

                context.Entry(campaignToDelete).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Because I am getting error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

So how can I avoid that?

Comment: have you enabled lazy loading?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading should be enabled by default when using *virtual*.

This may be helpful:
[How to disable cascade delete for link tables in EF code-first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705441/how-to-disable-cascade-delete-for-link-tables-in-ef-code-first)

Answer (score 0):

1) What kind of object do you pass to the *DeleteCampaign* method?
I think that is one of your entity framwork proxy models, which was queried by another database context. 
You access in your for-loop the linked *User* object, which could not be loaded because the context doesn't exist anymore.

```
for (int i = 0; i < campaignToDelete.Users.Count; i++) {
```

Don't mix objects of different database contexts.

Better way is, that you pass the ID of the Campaign to the *DeleteCampaign* method and then you have to query the campaign in the new database context. 
After that you can do all operations in one using statement (= the same database context).

```
static void DeleteCampaign(int idOfCampaignToDelete)
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var campaignToDelete = context.Campaigns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == idOfCampaignToDelete);
            for (int i = 0; i < campaignToDelete.Users.Count; i++)
            {
                campaignToDelete.Users[i].Campaign = context.Campaigns.ElementAt(0);
            }

            context.Entry(campaignToDelete).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

2) You cannot use ElementAt(0) in a LINQ to Entities query.
Use .FirstOrDefault().

```
campaignToDelete.Users[i].Campaign = context.Campaign.FirstOrDefault();
```

3) Make the CampaignId in your User class nullable. Otherwise you cannot have Users without Campaigns, because the Foreign Key would not be nullable.

```
public int? CampaignId {get; set;}
```

Now your code should work.