# ASP.NET MVC C# avoid delete cascade effect

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im trying to avoid cascading deleting by changing the Id of the delete item to null for all "Cats" that have the CatLitter Id. can someone tell me what i need to do. this is what i come up with so far im pretty sure im somewhere in the right direction.

Problem: when i delete CatLitter - All Cats that have CatLitterId also gets deleted.

```
    public ActionResult CatLittersDelete(int Id)
    {
        CatLitter ni = db.CatLitters.Find(Id);
        foreach (var item in ni.Cats.Where(m => m.CatLitterId == Id))
        {
            item.CatLitterId = null;
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.CatLitters.Remove(ni);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("CatPropCreate");
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Cat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int? CatLitterId { get; set; }
    public virtual CatLitter CatLitters { get; set; }
```

Using Entity Framework Code First.

So im trying this now from what u guys have given me:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>()
            .HasOptional<CatLitter>(s => s.CatLitters)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

but im getting this when i try update db.

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

CatProject.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CatProject.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable cascade delete for link tables in EF code-first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705441/how-to-disable-cascade-delete-for-link-tables-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: You have `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`, but is cascaded delete off in the database? I bet it isn't. The exception is about `IdentityUserRole`, so it's not related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it by adding this code.

```
public ActionResult CatLittersDelete(int? Id)
    {
        CatLitter ni = db.CatLitters.Find(Id);
        if (Id != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in ni.Cats.Where(m => m.CatLitterId == Id).ToList())
            {
                item.CatLitterId = null;
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        db.CatLitters.Remove(ni);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("CatPropCreate");
    }
```

still feel like its working the way around the problem i would love to know how to use the

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>()
        .HasOptional<CatLitter>(s => s.CatLitters)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

properly if anyone knows how to make that work i would appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CatLitter>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Cat)
        .WithMany(b => b.CatLitters)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.deletebehavior

Edit:  Changing the ID to null will probably not have the desired effect.  Try:

```
context.Remove(CatLitter);
context.SaveChanges();
```